# lubridate mdy family function error

Tags: r, lubridate

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949    LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 LC_NUMERIC=C                
[5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949
```

I'm using win7 32bit.

when I use mdy family function in lubridate, there is a error

```
> library(lubridate)
> mdy("07-31-2014")
Error in gsub("+", "*", fixed = T, gsub(">", "_e>", num)) : invalid multibyte string at '<ec><98><a4>?<84>|<ec>삤<ed>썑)(?![[:alpha:]]))|((?<H_s_e>2[0-4]|[01]?\d)\D+(?<M_s_e>[0-5]?\d)\D+((?<OS_s_S_e>[0-5]?\d\.\d+)|(?<S_s_e>[0-6]?\d))))'
```

what is this error message? And how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Does the basic as.POSIXct operation work okay? `as.POSIXct("07-31-2014",format="%m-%d-%Y",tz="UTC")`. I have no idea why this is erroring out, but I'm guessing it is something to do with a locale-specific Korean character ending up in the date processing somehow.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, as.POSIXct("07-31-2014",format="%m-%d-%Y",tz="UTC") works well.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue without a known fix. See here on the lubridate mailing list: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/181

Comment: I solved this problem.
I changed  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "usa")
Is there any problem using Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "usa") in korea ??